# Show harddisk activity in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I use system monitor to see cpu and ram activity but it doesn't show the harddisk activity like the ram utilization is showed in graph and its reading and writing  speed so how to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gnome shell extension called `gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor` can put a real-time graph into the top panel.

You need to install the Gnome Tweaks app along with the extension:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor
```

The newly installed Tweaks app will offer a user interface for managing shell extensions.

Shell extensions need to be enabled in general (look for the "Extensions" tab in the Tweaks app window), and then the "System Monitor" can be enabled in the list of extensions.

It's highly configurable. Maybe the "Disks" graph is not enabled by default, but via the preferences, it can be enabled.

To take full effect, might need logging out and back in.

Comment: How to see extionsions? @Levente

Comment: Please clarify. What steps did you do, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes I did the command given by you and I will logout and login later but don't know where to look for the extensions tab@Levente

Comment: Open the "Tweaks" app that just got installed. It has an "Extensions" tab. I also updated my answer.

Comment: Ok Thankyou I found it and I enabled all the options and also selected the preferences in system monitor and the disk write and disk read is already enabled but not showing its graph @Levente

Comment: Maybe now comes the part with the log out / log in.

Comment: Sorry but a last question please will it give a big impact on the performance. @Levente

Comment: I use it since one month, and did not experience anything of note. To me it seems it's stable and well written. Furthermore, the preferences make it possible to adjust refresh rates to each graphs. The more sparse the refresh rate, the smaller the impact on the system.

Comment: I installed `gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor`, but I don't see a "System Monitor" in the Extensions tab of Tweaks, even after reboot. I'm using Gnome 3.30.2 on Debian 10.